# How do I convert OHLC values to Renko chart in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, algorithmic-trading

I have been trying to match the Renko chart on Tradingview for the past few hours and still can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

So far my algo spits out the right values except in cases where the trend reverses.

```
import math
import pandas as pd


def bricks_series(df: pd.DataFrame, step=50):
    prices = df['close']
    first_brick = math.floor(prices.iloc[0] / step) * step
    bricks = [first_brick]
    for price in prices:
        if price > (bricks[-1] + step):
            step_mult = math.floor((price - bricks[-1]) / step)
            next_bricks = [bricks[-1] + (mult * step) for mult in range(1, step_mult + 1)]
            bricks += next_bricks
        elif price < bricks[-1] - step:
            step_mult = math.ceil((bricks[-1] - price) / step)
            next_bricks = [bricks[-1] - (mult * step) for mult in range(1, step_mult + 1)]
            bricks += next_bricks
        else:
            continue
    return bricks


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv("binance_daily.csv")
    renko_bricks = bricks_series(df)
```

Here is my ohlc data.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Psn8XYBwJ9F5JCTpF0ffxQx_vcLSFyD4

and here is the chart I am trying to replicate.
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/lyXNhcbs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use lib "Renko" to get renko-chart and also get renko-blocks and then convert to ohlc-dataframe
code:

```
# !pip install renko yfinance
from renko import Renko
import yfinance as yf
ticker = "AAPL"
ohlcv_data = yf.download(ticker, period="1y")
ohlcv_data.columns = ohlcv_data.columns.str.lower()
renko = Renko(brick_size=5, data=ohlcv_data.close)
renko.create_renko()
renko_ohlc = pd.DataFrame(renko.bricks)
# fill nan
mask_upL = renko_ohlc[renko_ohlc.type == 'up'].low.isna()
mask_upL = mask_upL[mask_upL == True].index
mask_downL = renko_ohlc[renko_ohlc.type == 'down'].low.isna()
mask_downL = mask_downL[mask_downL == True].index
mask_upH = renko_ohlc[renko_ohlc.type == 'up'].high.isna()
mask_upH = mask_upH[mask_upH == True].index
mask_downH = renko_ohlc[renko_ohlc.type == 'down'].high.isna()
mask_downH = mask_downH[mask_downH == True].index
renko_ohlc.loc[mask_upL, 'low'] = renko_ohlc.loc[mask_upL, 'open']
renko_ohlc.loc[mask_downL, 'low'] = renko_ohlc.loc[mask_downL, 'close']
renko_ohlc.loc[mask_upH, 'high'] = renko_ohlc.loc[mask_upH, 'close']
renko_ohlc.loc[mask_downH, 'high'] = renko_ohlc.loc[mask_downH, 'open']
renko_ohlc = renko_ohlc[1:]
print(renko_ohlc)
renko.draw_chart()
```

Output chart:
[image]
Output ohlc-dataframe:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use that one as an example : https://github.com/carlfarterson/TAcharts/blob/master/TAcharts/indicators/renko.py

I tested it and it's working well. Not exactly the same than tradingview so maybe you have to tune it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a red renko brick, you put an extra +1 in range().

The following code produces the right data:

```
def bricks_series(df: pd.DataFrame, step=50):
    prices = df['close']
    first_brick = math.floor(prices.iloc[0] / step) * step
    bricks = [first_brick]
    for price in prices:
        if price > (bricks[-1] + step):
            step_mult = math.floor((price - bricks[-1]) / step)
            next_bricks = [bricks[-1] + (mult * step) for mult in range(1, step_mult + 1)]
            bricks += next_bricks
        elif price < bricks[-1] - step:
            step_mult = math.ceil((bricks[-1] - price) / step)
            next_bricks = [bricks[-1] - (mult * step) for mult in range(1, step_mult)]
            bricks += next_bricks
        else:
            continue
    return bricks
```

If you want a code with the exact same open/close renko bricks as Trading View, you can use this code:

```
def get_renko(timestamps, close, step):
    prices = close
    first_brick = {
        'timestamp': timestamps.iloc[0],
        'open': math.floor(prices.iloc[0] / step) * step,
        'close': math.floor((prices.iloc[0] / step)+1) * step
    }
    bricks = [first_brick]
    for price, timestamp in zip(prices, timestamps):
        if price > (bricks[-1]['close'] + step):
            step_mult = math.floor((price - bricks[-1]['close']) / step)
            next_bricks = [{
                'timestamp': timestamp,
                'open': bricks[-1]['close'] + (mult * step),
                'close': bricks[-1]['close'] + ((mult + 1) * step)
            } for mult in range(1, step_mult)]
            bricks += next_bricks

        elif price < bricks[-1]['close'] - step:
            step_mult = math.ceil((bricks[-1]['close'] - price) / step)
            next_bricks = [{
                'timestamp': timestamp,
                'open': bricks[-1]['close'] - (mult * step),
                'close': bricks[-1]['close'] - ((mult + 1) * step)
            } for mult in range(1, step_mult-1)]
            bricks += next_bricks

        else:
            continue

    return pd.DataFrame(bricks)
```